# How to make transmission work for all users

Tags: transmission, multiple-users

I tried opening a magnet link from a different (standard) user I created and it didn't work. It asked me to choose a program to open it with. There was no list of programs to choose from. 
I also tried browsing for programs, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

When the dialog window to choose the program pops out, you need to select `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk`